# Как проверить правильность Regex во время работы?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, c#

Предположим, регулярное выражение не задается в явном виде в коде, а вводится пользователем программы во время работы приложения или извлекается из файла настроек и т.п. Заранее неизвестно, будет ли это регулярное выражение правильным: оно вполне может содержать произвольные ошибки. Я просмотрел описание класса [Regex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/6f7hht7k.aspx) и не нашел явного способа проверить выражение на правильность. Вопрос, как это сделать?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Когда будет создаваться экземпляр `Regex` от строчки, если паттерн был синтаксически некорректен, из конструктора прилетит [`ArgumentException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/43122zyz.aspx).

```
try {
    Regex r = new Regex(pattern);
} catch (ArgumentException) {
}
```